# upgrade asp.net core targeting from vs2015 to vs2017 - Error

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I have multiple projects in the solution where the main application is referencing them by project reference.

When running the application I get below error:

> One or more compilation references are missing. Ensure that your
>   project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' and the
>   'PreserveCompilationContext' property is not set to false.

[image]

and below is my `.csproj` file contents:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackageId>web.demo.Portal</PackageId>
    <PackageVersion>$(PackageVersion)</PackageVersion>
    <VersionSuffix>$(VersionSuffix)</VersionSuffix>
    <Authors>demo auth</Authors>
    <Description>test</Description>
    <PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>false</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>
    <Copyright>Copyright 2017 (c) demo.</Copyright>
    <PackageTags>portal</PackageTags>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="..\xyz.Objects\xyz.Objects.csproj" />
...
...
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Can anyone suggest me what changes I required to make project run successfully.

Any help will be appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: Have you done what the message said?

Comment: @john i added `<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>` in .csproj file but it didn't work for me .. can you guide me what steps I should follow

Comment: Do you have a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`?